# Использовать изображение рабочего стола телефона как фон приложения

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Может кто подскажет, как установить фоном приложения картинку рабочего стола телефона? Как у стандартного приложения Погода на айфоне.

Answer (score 0):

На [форумах Apple](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52268) пишут, что нет возможности это сделать. Я находил возможности работы с wallpaper, но лишь через Private API.